# in Java I am redirecting System.out to a ByteArrayOutputStream but it is not working - why?

Tags: java, system.out

I have the following class:

```java
class Bla {
   private static final Consumer<String> OUTPUT = System.out::println;

   public void print() {
      printStuff(OUTPUT);
   }

   public void printStuff(Consumer<String> consumer) {
      consumer.accept("Bla");

   }
}
```

Test code:

```java
Bla bla = new Bla();
ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
final PrintStream standardOut = System.out;
System.setOut(new PrintStream(baos));
bla.print();
LOG.info(baos.toString().trim()); <-- This does not work
System.setOut(standardOut);
```

It logs nothing. Why? When I inline OUTPUT, then it works.

Comment: What is `LOG`? I can infer that it's some sort of logging framework, but which one may be relevant. And the only place you use `OUTPUT` is in the `Bla.print` function, which is never even called here. I don't understand what you *expect* to happen.

Comment: And since `print` / `printStuff` is never called, `baos.toString()` will be empty when you call `LOG.info(...)`.

Answer (score 4):

The problem is that when the `Bla` class initializes, it takes a reference to `System.out` *at that point in time*.  When you reset `System.out` in the subsequent code, it has no affect on the value of `Bla.OUTPUT`.

I think this will do what you want:

```
OUTPUT = s -> System.out.println(s);
```

because it will always use the current value of `System.out`.